# What does mod 2^64 addition actually means in cryptography?

Tags: binary

I am trying to develop SHA-512 algorithm in python. But in the algorithm, there is a term "+" which describes that mod 2^64 addition. But I am very much confused about the mod 2^64 addition and XOR operation. Can anyone help me with the difference between mod 2^64 addition and XOR operation? 
I have 2 binary numbers as below:

```
a = "0110110111011101110100110101111000001101100010111100010010010010"
and 
b = "1110101000101001100100101001001000001010010000111011110111101000"
```

So, What is the output of the following statement?

```
c = a + b (here "+" mod 2^64 addition)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone help me with the difference between mod 2^64 addition and XOR operation?

They are very different. The simplest example: 1 + 1 mod 2^64 is 2 (10 in binary); 1 xor 1 is 0.

Instead of adding these large numbers, let's simplify to see what's going on and add e.g. 1110 + 1100 mod 2^4. Without the mod you get

```
 1110 + 
 1100 =
11010
```

(do you understand why?). mod 2^4 means you need to take only the right 4 digits and get 1010.

Comment: Is the answer 1110 or 1010? The answer is unclear to me.

Comment: @Fahim.csedu Sorry, I had a typo initially and only fixed it in one place. It's 1010.